How Can I append a recordId with href url in anchor tag
I have a lwc table where I have created buttons. I am using a url inside the href attribute and it is redirecting me to a other page as expected but I need to append the recordId with url inside href, so that correct recordId should be visible . I am trying to append the recordId but the recordId is not  showing.
The expected url should this :- /i-need-a-broker/?BrokerId=001Da00000xln40IAA.
But I getting this :- /i-need-a-broker?BrokerId=%7B!acc.Id%7D
accountId = {acc.Id}
Contact Broker
View Details

Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you have an object called acc with an Id property, and you want to include the value of the Id property in the URL as the value of the BrokerId parameter? Whereas what's actually happening is that {acc.Id} is being included in the URL as a literal string, and has been percent encoded because { and } are not valid characters in a URL. Is this JavaScript code? If so, please edit the question to show the code which is building the URL.

You may also want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting
